# Unity: UI prefabs go invisible when i Instantiate it

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a custom UI element in the Mainmenu scene that works fine, but when i make a prefab out of it, all the text and images become invisible, and the rect transform goes blank

[The orginal prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EktbY.jpg)

[the instatiated invisible prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e54n9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate it as a child object of Canvas.

```
Instantiate(prefab, thatCanvas.transform);
```

Comment: @Alex If it worked, upvote and accept this answer. Also, be wary that the transform of the saved prefab might use a different `Canvas` as its reference, and might deform when instantiated; especially if you use different Canvas Scaler settings across scenes.